# Add Peer to AWS

Tags: private-blockchain

I have created my private network over AWS and created two node and add them as peer which is working fine and node are connected.

Now i want to setup third node on my local machine which is not AWS machine, I created  the node but not able to add it as peer over AWS.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Is the P2P port 30303 open in AWS and your local machine?

Comment: Did not check. will check and let you know. Thanks :)